# Hide Taskbar on fullscreen WPF

Tags: wpf, window, hide, taskbar, maximize

recently i had tried to make task-bar invisible in maximize mode but unfortunately nothing worked.
i had some research over MSDN and stack overflow and most of them said make window border equal to none and maximize window.but it didn't worked.
BTW: i am using Metro-window and it has a hide task-bar functionality by itself.but it didn't worked either.

Comment: did you try to set window border equal to none and set with/height window to screen with /height after form loading?

Comment: border brush naturally is none and yes i tried seting window height/width manually but didn't worked.this is my exact defination of window:  <code>Title="Fullscreen" Height="406.225" Width="754" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized" IgnoreTaskbarOnMaximize="True" ShowCloseButton="False" ShowTitleBar="False" ShowInTaskbar="False"</code>

Comment: I opened up a new WPF project and added `WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized" ShowInTaskbar="False"` to the Window properties. It worked correctly for me. Maybe your metro-window extension is messing things up.

Comment: thanks you're right. it was metro window's bug (i had doubt but i had so many taughts about other aspects of project and i forgot to try a new project without metro window)

Answer (score 8):

My experience on Windows 8.1 is that setting `WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized"` (as most people say) is not enough.

To hide taskbar I had to set `ResizeMode="NoResize"`

Comment: Thanks for that tip, it did the trick but it was important to set it **before** setting the `WindowStyle` and `WindowState` (at least when doing it programatically). Hope this little info helps those struggeling^^